# Define an empty object without optional keys

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to define an empty object without defining initial values.

My interface

```
interface MyDate {
  day: string;
  month: string;
  year: string;
}
```

My class

```
export class MyClass implements OnInit {
  date: MyDate = {}; // Error Type '{}' is missing the following properties ...
  buildDate([day, month, year]: Array<string>) {
    this.date = { day, month, year };
  }
}
```

I can change my interface to set keys as optional:

```
interface MyDate {
  day?: number;
  month?: number;
  year?: number;
}
```

Or initiate my object like:

```
date: MyDate = {
  day: '';
  month: '';
  year: '';
};
```

But I want to initiate an empty object for beauty purposes ))

Comment: `date: MyDate | null = null`

Comment: @MahdiRezazadeh because the question doesn't make sense. You define the properties as mandatory but then you don't want to initialize them. Well are they mandatory or not? You're just defeating the purpose of creating the interface in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `as` statement, but this is not good practice.

```
date: MyDate = {} as MyDate;
```

Comment: this works for my purpose, why is a bad practice ?

Comment: When we use `as` we are telling TypeScript that we know what type is in the variable being used (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions). This is definitely useful, for example in the type guards (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards), but in general better to build code so that TypeScript itself infers the types that are obtained in the process of building the logic of your code. However, if you are not particularly strict about data types, you can safely use `as` statement.

Comment: @maxypayne because it allows runtime errors. Put `date.day.length` on the next line and the code will compile but you'll get a runtime error that `date.day` is `undefined`. The purpose of typescript is to minimize the risk of runtime errors by catching them at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want the properties to be automatically instantiated? Just use a class

```js
class MyDate {
  day = '';
  month = '';
  year = '';
}
```

```js
date = new MyDate();
buildDate([day, month, year]: Array<string>) {
  this.date = { day, month, year };
}
```

This way you still follow your object definition - the properties are in fact all strings.

If you define an interface with mandatory properties and then instantiate an empty object, your properties will all be undefined. So you just made the rule that all properties are strings, and proceeded to break that rule. Why bother making the rule in the first place?